# How to update my ubuntu desktop from 12.10 to 15.04?

Tags: 12.10, updates, 15.04

I'm not able to update my ubuntu desktop. When I open the software updater it says you should upgrade to ubuntu 13.10. When I click upgrade, the update doesn't start the software updater closes automatically. Please help.

Comment: You can not upgrade 12.10 directly to anything now. Previously it could be upgraded to 13.04. But now both are not supported for a long time. I suggest a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It will be supported till 2019.

Comment: @ Karel: upgrading won't work at all anymore in this setup. OP has an unsupported version, and the next version is also unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1) 12.10 is a **Short Term Release**.

- Upgrading on **Short Term Releases** is less reliable than doing fresh installs.
- Upgrading on **Long Term Releases** such as 10.04, 12.04, and 14.04 is however perfectly fine and supported.

2) 12.10 is an old release, and no longer officially supported.

- Support ended long ago in 2014: [image: Support]
- It is very likely that even if you could some how get this to upgrade, that you will have severe issues with stability. I am speaking from experience.

It is recommended that you do a fresh install of the Ubuntu Operating System to replace a short term release. Instructions can be found here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop